# Check if name matches another sheet and if so return info in cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a database filled with all the current and past members of the organization. I need to check weekly that the people registering for events who apply for a member discount are actually a member. I have a the weekly event registrations in a spreadsheet, which I check against the total member list.

At the moment I am running this

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH('Registrations Report'!F2,Sheet1!$K:$K,0),"yes",),"no")
```

which lets me know if the people registering for an event are a member in our database.

Instead of just return a `Yes` or `No`, I would like it to be able to determine what their membership status is; e.g., `active` or `expired` if they are a member, or `No` if not.

As I don't have a membership number to check against, I am just combining their first and last name and using that information. It isn't 100%, as some people have used an abbreviated name, but then any No's I get I double check manually in the database.

Comment: What's in F2? In what column on the Registrations Report is the membership status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that F2 has the name and column K on sheet1 is a column of names, also assuming that membership status is in column Z on sheet1, you could do

```
=IFERROR(Index(Sheet1!$z:$z,MATCH('Registrations Report'!F2,Sheet1!$K:$K,0)),"no")
```

If the name is found in column K, the value from column Z is returned. If there is no match, an error will be returned and the "no" will display.

Comment: YES! This solved it. You were correct with your assumptions, sorry for not adding more data. I am new to excel formulas and couldn't figure it out